# How to associate .slx file with Simulink

Tags: simulink

I would like to be able to double-click a .slx file and have it open up in Simulink.  If MATLAB is already open, I would prefer that it not open a second instance of MATLAB.

Challenges include:

- unable to find .exe to associate .slx file with
- Google search did not reveal solution to this challenge

Actionable suggestions or examples are appreciated

Associating .slx with matlab.exe looks like this:

[image]

My peers with OSX show .slx associated with this icon:

[image]

[Starting the Simulink Software](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/starting-simulink-software.html)

Comment: You associate it with matlab.exe.

Comment: Thanks for responding Phil.  Does your system open up the .slx file in the Simulink editor?  Is there syntax that will launch the file with the Simulink editor?  I had tried this with a 2015a and it would open a new instance of MATLAB each time and not open the .SLX file in the Simulink editor.

Comment: For me, R2015b, on Windows, does everything you have asked for in your question.

Comment: Works in R2014b also.  Can't believe it doesn't in R2015a.

Comment: @Phil: I am encouraged by your results:  I associated .slx with C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\matlab.exe. and the .slx file is shown with a Matlab symbol.   The .slx double-click behavior observed is as described with 2015a (.slx file does not open, but Matlab window opens).  A peer has the Mac version and .slx files show a Simulink icon.  Should I associate it with a different file?  Did you have to associate your .slx files or was this automagically done for you at install?

Comment: Automatically associated with R2015b on installation.  Manually changed to R2014b to test it.  Manually changed back to R2015b.

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for response.  Do .slx file (when view in file explorer) associate with this icon: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ojEyN.jpg?

Comment: Yes, that is the Simulink icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. Here is the [solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51165-matlab-file-association-fix?s_tid=mwa_osa_a), it worked fine for my R2018b.

Run this file in Matlab and it will produce .reg file that will fix the problem (run it of course). Than restart yor PC.

Here is the code of the file if you can't (or don't want to) sign in to download it:

```
function associateFiles(action, userExtList, fileStr)

% Defualt input
if (nargin < 1 || isempty(action))
  action      = 'add';
end
if (nargin < 2)
  userExtList = {};
end
if (nargin < 3)
  fileStr = '';
end
if (~iscell(userExtList))
  if (isempty(userExtList))
    userExtList = {};
  else
    userExtList = {userExtList};
  end
end

% Sanity check
if (~ischar(action) || (~strcmpi(action, 'add') && ...
    ~strcmpi(action, 'delete') && ~strcmpi(action, 'deleteadd')))
  error('The action to perform must be ''add'', ''delete'' or ''deleteadd''!')
end
if (~isempty(userExtList) && ~min(cellfun(@ischar, userExtList)))
  error('The file extension list must be a string or a cell array of strings!')
end
if (~ischar(fileStr))
  error('The file to write to must be a string!')
end


% Get the currently running MATLAB version
verStr = regexp(version, '(\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*?)\.', 'tokens');
verStr = verStr{1}{1};
verNum = str2double(regexprep(verStr, '(\d*?\.\d*)[\x0000-\xffff]*', '$1'));
verHex = sprintf('%04x', str2double(regexprep(verStr, ...
  '(\d*?)\.[\x0000-\xffff]*', '$1')), str2double(regexprep(verStr, ...
  '\d*?\.(\d*?)\.[\x0000-\xffff]*', '$1')));

% Get 32/64-bit
arch = computer;
switch arch
  case 'PCWIN'
    binFolder = 'win32';
  case 'PCWIN64'
    binFolder = 'win64';
end
binPath = fullfile(matlabroot, 'bin', binFolder);


% Known MATLAB files with possible DDE actions
fileExtCell = {...
  'fig' ,   'MATLAB Figure'              , '-62'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , []                          ; ...
  'm'     , 'MATLAB Code'                , '-58'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , {'Run', 'run(''%1'')'}      ; ...
  'mat'   , 'MATLAB Data'                , '-59'                       , ...
  {'Load', 'load(''%1'')'    }           , {'Open', 'uiimport(''%1'')'}; ...
  'mdl'   , 'Simulink Model'             , '-61'                       , ...
  {'Load', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , []                          ; ...
  'mdlp'  , 'Simulink Protected Model'   , '-72'                       , ...
  []                                     , []                          ; ...
  'mexw32', 'MATLAB MEX'                 , '-63'                       , ...
  []                                     , []                          ; ...
  'mexw64', 'MATLAB MEX'                 , '-63'                       , ...
  []                                     , []                          ; ...
  'mn'    , 'MuPAD Notebook'             , '-66'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'mupad(''%1'')'}              , []                          ; ...
  'mu'    , 'MuPAD Code'                 , '-67'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , []                          ; ...
  'muphlp', 'MuPAD Help'                 , '-68'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'doc(symengine, ''%1'')'}     , []                          ; ...
  'p'     , 'MATLAB P-code'              , '-60'                       , ...
  []                                     , []                          ; ...
  'slx'   , 'Simulink Model (SLX format)', '-73'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , []                          ; ...
  'ssc'   , 'Simscape Model'             , '-65'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'uiopen(''%1'',1)'}           , []                          ; ...
  'xvc'   , 'MuPAD Graphics'             , '-69'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'mupad(''%1'')'}              , []                          ; ...
  'xvz'   , 'MuPAD Graphics'             , '-70'                       , ...
  {'Open', 'mupad(''%1'')'}              , []                          ; ...
  'mlapp'       , 'MATLAB Application'              , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'mltbx'       , 'MATLAB Toolbox'                  , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'mldatx'      , 'Simulink Scenario'               , [] , [], []      ; ...  
  'req'         , 'Simulink Requirements Link'      , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'sldd'        , 'Simulink Dictionary'             , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'slddc'       , 'Simulink Dictionary'             , [] , [], []      ; ...      
  'mlappinstall', 'MATLAB Application'              , [] , [], []      ; ...  
  'mlpkginstall', 'MATLAB Support Package'          , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'slxp'        , 'Simulink Protected Model Package', [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'sltx'        , 'Simulink Template'               , [] , [], []      ; ... 
  'mlprj'       , 'MATLAB Project'                  , [] , [], []};

% Possibly trim list
if (~isempty(userExtList))
  fileExtCell = fileExtCell(ismember(fileExtCell(:, 1), ...
    regexprep(userExtList, '\.', '')), :);
end

% Make registry file
if (~isempty(fileStr))
  % Possibly add file extension
  [~, ~, tmp] = fileparts(fileStr);
  if (isempty(tmp))
    fileStr = [fileStr, '.reg'];
  end
  fid = fopen(fileStr, 'w');
else
  fid = fopen('MatlabFileAssocFix.reg', 'w');
end
if (fid == -1)
  error('Failed to create registry file')
end
% Write intial lines
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', 'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00');
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', ';FIXES MATLAB FILE ASSOCIATIONS');


% REMOVE OLD KEYS
explorerKey = ['HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\', ...
  'CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts'];
% Iterate over file extensions
for fileExtNo = 1 : size(fileExtCell, 1)
  rmKeys  = {};
  fileExt = fileExtCell{fileExtNo, 1};

  % File extension keys
  [status, result] = dos(['reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /f .', fileExt, ...
    ' /k /e']);
  if (~status)
    keys = regexp(result, '(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT[\x0000-\xffff]*?)\n', 'tokens');
    rmKeys = [rmKeys, keys{:}];
  end

  % Old style keys without version numbers
  if (~strcmpi(fileExt, 'mexw64'))
    % Uses single DDE key for mex files
    if (strcmpi(fileExt, 'mexw32'))
      fileExtTmp = 'mex';
    else
      fileExtTmp = fileExt;
    end
    [status, result] = dos(['reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /f ', ...
      fileExtTmp, 'file /k /e']);
    if (~status)
      keys = regexp(result, '(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT[\x0000-\xffff]*?)\n', ...
        'tokens');
      rmKeys = [rmKeys, keys{:}];
    end
  end

  % New style keys with version number
  if (strcmpi(action, 'add'))
    % Only remove keys related to this version
    [status, result] = dos(['reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /f MATLAB.', ...
      fileExt, '.', verStr ' /k']);
  else
    % Remove keys related to ALL version
    [status, result] = dos(['reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /f MATLAB.', ...
      fileExt, '. /k']);
  end
  if (~status)
    keys = regexp(result, '(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT[\x0000-\xffff]*?)\n', 'tokens');
    rmKeys = [rmKeys, keys{:}];
  end

  % Explorer keys
  [status, result] = dos(['reg query ', explorerKey, ' /f .', fileExt, ...
    ' /k /e']);
  if (~status)
    keys = regexp(result, '(HKEY_CURRENT_USER[\x0000-\xffff]*?)\n', 'tokens');
    rmKeys = [rmKeys, keys{:}];
  end

  % Write to file
  if (~isempty(rmKeys))
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', [';REMOVES ', upper(fileExt), ...
      ' FILE ASSOCIATIONS']);
    for keyNo = 1 : length(rmKeys)
      key = rmKeys{keyNo};
      fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', ['[-', key, ']']);
    end
  end
end

% ADD KEYS
if (~strcmpi(action, 'delete'))
  % Get text Persistent Handler
  [status, result] = dos(...
    'reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler /ve');
  if (~status)
    PersistentHandler = regexp(result, '\{[\x0000-\xffff]*?\}', 'match');
    PersistentHandler = PersistentHandler{1};
  else
    PersistentHandler = '';
  end
  % DDE call
  ddeCall = 'ShellVerbs.Matlab';
  if (verNum > 8)
    % Changed from R2013a
    ddeCall = [ddeCall, '.', verStr];
  end
  % Default icon
  defIcon = 'm';
  if (~exist(fullfile(binPath, 'm.ico'), 'file'))
    defIcon = '';
  end
  % Path to MATLAB binary directory with \\
  binPathStr = regexprep(binPath, '\\', '\\\\');

  % Write Shell Open key
  key = ['[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MATLAB.exe\shell\open', ...
    '\command]%r', '@="\"', binPathStr, '\\MATLAB.exe\" \"%1\""%r%r'];
  fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', ';ADD SHELL OPEN');
  lines = regexp(key, '([\x0000-\xffff]*?)%r', 'tokens');
  for lineNo = 1 : length(lines)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', lines{lineNo}{1});
  end

  % Iterate over file types
  for fileExtNo = 1 : size(fileExtCell, 1)
    fileExt = fileExtCell{fileExtNo, 1};

    % File extension keys
    key  = ['[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.', fileExt, ']%r@="MATLAB.', fileExt, '.', ...
      verStr, '"%r'];
    if (strcmpi(fileExt, 'm') && ~isempty(PersistentHandler))
      % Add some values
      key = [key, '"Content Type"="text/plain"%r', ...
        '"PerceivedType"="Text"%r'];
    end
    key = [key, '%r'];
    key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.', fileExt, ...
      '\OpenWithProgids]%r"MATLAB.', fileExt, '.', verStr, '"=""%r%r'];
    if (strcmpi(fileExt, 'm') && ~isempty(PersistentHandler))
      key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.', fileExt, ...
        '\PersistentHandler]%r@="', PersistentHandler, '"%r%r'];
    end
    key  = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.', fileExt, ...
      '\Versions\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ']%r"FileVersionMS"=dword:', ...
      verHex, '%r"FileVersionLS"=dword:00000000%r%r'];

    % DDE keys
    ddeData = fileExtCell(ismember(fileExtCell(:, 1), fileExt), :);
    key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
      ']%r@="', ddeData{2}, '"%r'];
    if (~isempty(ddeData{3}))
      key = [key, '"FriendlyTypeName"="@', binPathStr, '\\matlab.exe', ...
        ',', ddeData{3}, '"%r'];
    end
    key = [key, '%r'];
    % Icon
    icon = fileExt;
    if (~exist(fullfile(binPath, [icon, '.ico']), 'file'))
      icon = defIcon;
    end
    if (~isempty(icon))
      key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
        '\DefaultIcon]%r@="', binPathStr, '\\', icon, '.ico,0"%r%r'];
    end
    % Shell actions
    for shellActionNo = 4:5
      ddePar = ddeData{shellActionNo};
      if (~isempty(ddePar))
        key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
          '\Shell\', ddePar{1}, ']%r@="', ddePar{1}, '"%r%r'];
        key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
          '\Shell\', ddePar{1}, '\command]%r@="\"', binPathStr, ...
          '\\matlab.exe\""%r%r'];
        key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
          '\Shell\', ddePar{1}, '\ddeexec]%r@="', ddePar{2}, '"%r%r'];
        key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
          '\Shell\', ddePar{1},'\ddeexec\application]%r@="', ...
          ddeCall, '"%r%r'];
        key = [key, '[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.', fileExt, '.' verStr, ...
          '\Shell\', ddePar{1},'\ddeexec\topic]%r@="system"%r%r'];
      end
    end

    % Explorer keys
    key = [key, '[', explorerKey, '\.', fileExt, '\OpenWithProgids]%r'];
    if (strcmpi(fileExt, 'm'))
      key = [key, '"m_auto_file"=hex(0):%r'];
    end
    key = [key, '"MATLAB.', fileExt, '.',  verStr, '"=hex(0):%r%r'];
    if (~isempty(ddeData{4}))
      % Add key
      key = [key, '[', explorerKey, '\.', fileExt, ...
        '\OpenWithList]%r"a"="MATLAB.exe"%r"MRUList"="a"%r%r'];
    else
      key = [key, '[', explorerKey, '\.', fileExt, '\OpenWithList]%r%r'];
    end
    % Write to file
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n\r\n', [';ADD ', upper(fileExt), ...
      ' FILE ASSOCIATIONS']);
    lines = regexp(key, '([\x0000-\xffff]*?)%r', 'tokens');
    for lineNo = 1 : length(lines)
      fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', lines{lineNo}{1});
    end
  end

end

% Cloese file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: This is for Windows only?

Comment: @gatorback sure, because you create registry file (registry is a Windows specific thing)